# lvalue required as left operand of assignment?

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string itmCndtn,itemName;
int strtPrice,sellValue,numRelist,optn=0;

class CBAY_ITEM
{
    string enterName();
    string enterCondition();
    int enterStrtPrc();
    int enterSellVal();  
};

CBAY_ITEM infoClass;
CBAY_ITEM *nPointer=NULL;


int main()
{
    int optionChosen=0;
    int strtPrcTemp=0,sellValueTemp=0;
    do
    {
        cout << "\nPlease Enter a Choice From the Menu.\n"<<endl;
        cout << "\n1.Add an Item to Selling Queue.\n2.Put Item for Sale.\n3.Show Me the Money.\n4.Exit." << endl;
        cin>>optionChosen;
        switch(optionChosen)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            nPointer=new CBAY_ITEM;
            nPointer->enterName()=infoClass.enterName();
            nPointer->enterCondition()=infoClass.enterCondition();
            nPointer->enterStrtPrc()=infoClass.enterStrtPrc();
            nPointer->enterSellVal()=infoClass.enterSellVal();

        }
        case 2:
        {

        }
        case 3:
        {

        }

        }

    }while(optionChosen!=4);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my code so far, I omitted the definition of the functions within the class as it doesn't seem like thats where the problem is. When I try to compile, compiler shows an error saying

```
lvalue required as left operand of assignment.
```

I am not sure what it is trying to say.

```
nPointer->enterStrtPrc()=infoClass.enterStrtPrc();
nPointer->enterSellVal()=infoClass.enterSellVal();
```

are supposed to return int values and store them in the dynamically created class `infoClass`.

Comment: Add `break` at the end of each case block: otherwise, you will fall through.

Comment: @AdrianPanasiuk thanx, I was going to add them once I was done with all the coding.

Comment: Which means that when, for example, optionChosen == 1, then first the code from block `case 1:` will execute, then the code for `case 2:`, and so on. (because you don't have break which means don't exeecute the next case block)

Comment: Does this make sense to you? `1 = 5;`

Comment: @EdS. no, as one of the answerer said, need to use the address rather than the raw value.

Comment: @user2086751: Well you asked the question... so obviously you didn't understand the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your member functions to return references:

```
struct CBAY_ITEM
{
    string & enterName();
    string & enterCondition();
    int & enterStrtPrc();
    int & enterSellVal();
};
```

(And also get the access control right.)

Comment: `int CBAY_ITEM::enterStrtPrc()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter Starting Price: ";
    cin >> strtPrice;
    return strtPrice;
}`

Now the compiler says the definition doesnt match? What do I need to change in the definition?

Comment: @user2086751: Err... the same thing?!

Comment: I already tried `int CBAY_ITEM:: &enterStrtPrc()` which doesn't work. Sorry I am just very new to C++.

Comment: @user2086751: It's `int & CBAY_ITEM::enterStrtPrc()`. Check out our FAQ for a list of decent C++ textbooks. At your level, learning via StackOverflow is probably not terribly productive.

Comment: btw, its a `class` not `struct`.

Comment: @user2086751: As I said, "get your access control right"... Please consider reading those books...

Answer (score 0):

nPointer->enterStrtPrc() is an expression that returns rvalue. say the number 5. you cannot assign into it - it's as sensible as `5=infoClass.enterStrtPrc();`

if you'll change the return types to reference, as @Kerrek SB suggested, it will return the storage in which you can put the values you want.